# How to create a global variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I am a student and I am currently learning jQuery.

Create a toDos global variable holding three to do items, wake up, eat breakfast, and code.

I figured I need to make a global variable of type array which holds the three items, but I have no idea how to write this in jQuery, any tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery library is build from JavaScript.  Here is how to create global variable in JavaScript.

```
var data = ["wake up","eat breakfast","code"];

alert(data[0]);  // will display "wake up"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
window.doDos = Jquery.doDos = {
   wakeUp: 'value',
   breakfast: 'value',
   items: [some array here],
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'window.toDos' jquery as such does not have globals. It is just a library. only the window which hoists the execution context has globals

Read more here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, but what exactly is the window considered to be and can you make 1 window with a global variable within it then display items in it ?

Comment: window is a single global object . Please read more on the execution contexts . https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-execution-context/ ( i am not the author ) i  found it helpful